# In Altered Carbon, do sleeves need rest?

Tags: altered-carbon

I'm writing a short story set in the world about a family of three that share a sleeve and it got me wondering if the sleeve needs rest if the inhabitant is always being switched out.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe they would need rest? (I haven’t watched the show or read the books by the way).

Comment: IIRC it's really unclear if actual cognition is taking place on the stack, or if it's taking place in the sleeve's brain with the state being written to the stack.  The fact that the optic, auditory, etc. nerves aren't described as being wired into the stack makes me (personal gut-feel) believe the latter.  But even if the brain doesn't need to sleep (and replenish neurotransmitters, etc.) the organs and tissues of the body will still need down-time to repair.

Comment: @DavidW That makes the most sense to me, and is a good enough answer. I was planning on carving out 3 8-hour segments of the day, but figured switching every morning would be good enough.